# Any way to receive events from Stripe without using Public Sites

Tags: webhooks, stripe

I am trying to send some events from Stripe to my SF org by using Apex Rest API. The events get sent fine when using a public site as the endpoint. But is there any other way to send them to SF without using public sites?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The answer is no. Your question is an example of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The real question you want to ask is how to mitigate whatever risk you think is a risk in this architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)!

It depends on how these events are sent from Stripe - if it is just a simple webhook, then likely not.

But if you have some control to configure Stripe to send using OAuth 2.0, get authorized, then send a second time with whatever payload you want, you could possibly set up a Connected App < https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_about.htm > in Salesforce.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah for now it is a simple webhook, but I appreciate your response. It is a step to the right direction I suppose. Cheers